# sudo update-manager -d non-gui only alternative

Tags: command-line, update-manager

`sudo update-manager -d` *checks if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible* (source: `man update-manager`).

But it opens a visual application (windows, buttons and so on).

Is there any command alternative that does the same thing but in terminal only (without launching any window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do-release-upgrade` is the command recommended for server updating, I expect it to work for you.

Comment: But that also executes the upgrade. The -d only -checks-.

Comment: It actually does upgrade. Try it!

Comment: @Rinzwind Seems that `do-release-upgrade -d` run the check. If it founds a new release it upgrades the machine to the new release. Am  I right? Type `man do-release-ugpgrade`.